# Nuxt.js: Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):

Tags: javascript, css-loader, nuxt.js

I installed Nuxt starter template the [recommended](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/installation/) way:

```
npx create-nuxt-app fffff
```

Once inside `fffff` I installed css-loder (`npm install --save-dev css-loader`) then I launched the server: `npm run dev`

I got this error message:

```
> fffff@1.0.0 dev /home/begueradj/fffff
> nuxt



 INFO  Building project

✔ success Builder initialized
✔ success Nuxt files generated


 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                                                         22:09:09

 error  in ./layouts/default.vue

Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):

/home/begueradj/fffff/layouts/default.vue
   89:1  error  Delete `··`                           prettier/prettier
   90:3  error  Delete `··`                           prettier/prettier
   91:1  error  Replace `······` with `····`          prettier/prettier
   92:1  error  Delete `··`                           prettier/prettier
   93:1  error  Replace `········` with `······`      prettier/prettier
   94:1  error  Delete `··`                           prettier/prettier
   95:1  error  Replace `········` with `······`      prettier/prettier
   96:1  error  Delete `··`                           prettier/prettier
   97:1  error  Replace `··········` with `········`  prettier/prettier
   98:7  error  Delete `··`                           prettier/prettier
   99:1  error  Delete `··`                           prettier/prettier
  100:7  error  Delete `··`                           prettier/prettier
  101:1  error  Delete `··`                           prettier/prettier
  102:7  error  Delete `··`                           prettier/prettier
  103:5  error  Delete `··`                           prettier/prettier
  104:1  error  Replace `····` with `··`              prettier/prettier
  105:1  error  Delete `··`                           prettier/prettier

✖ 17 problems (17 errors, 0 warnings)
  17 errors and 0 warnings potentially fixable with the `--fix` option.


 @ ./.nuxt/App.js 4:0-47 6:14-23
 @ ./.nuxt/index.js
 @ ./.nuxt/client.js
 @ multi webpack-hot-middleware/client?name=client&reload=true&timeout=30000&path=/__webpack_hmr ./.nuxt/client.js



 READY  Listening on http://localhost:3000
```

What causes this? How to fix it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The default source code generated by the `create-nuxt-app`doesn't respect the ESlint + Prettier rules.

Try to fix each rules manually:

eg. `91:1  error  Replace '······' with '····'` => replace 6 spaces by 4 spaces at the beginning of the line #91 of the file `layouts/default.vue`.

or

Fix all rules automatically with the following command:

```
npx prettier --write "**/*.{vue,js}"
```

Comment: that's nice, do you know how to set it that is it runs that all the time, e.g. on save?

Comment: yes! you can follow this doc to run a watcher: https://prettier.io/docs/en/watching-files.html

Comment: or, you may configure your Editor to run Prettier on save: https://prettier.io/docs/en/editors.html

Answer (score 2):

Not recommended but useful if you just want to play around

```js
  // nuxt.config.js
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios'
    // '@nuxtjs/eslint-module' :: bypass this module
  ],
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: I created a new nuxt app for the first time ever and couldn't get it running because of this ESLint error. This solved it for me, except that the module was under buildModules.